# var exports = module.exports = {} in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

What I get from previous posts and articles is that the exports object is located on the `global` object. I came across this code which confused me:

```
let blue = 'blue'
let red = 'red'

var exports = module.exports = {
    red,
    blue
};
```

This code sets  `module.exports` to a variable called `exports` which then gets set to an object which gets exported.

I am confused however by this syntax:

**Example1:**

```
var exports = module.exports = {}
```

How does this work exactly? Because normally in JS you can't assing a variable two times. For instance this gives an error:

**Example2:**

```
let foo = 5 = 4;
```

How does the code in example 1 give no error while the code in example 2 does?

Comment: It's `exports = (module.exports = {});`. It assigns the object (created from the object literal) to both targets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let foo = 5 = 4;
```

Cause its parsed from right to left:

```
let foo = (5 = 4);
```

And `5` is not a variable, so you cant assign stuff to it. However it works with an identifier:

```
let bar;
let foo = bar = 5;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your interpretation of what the line is doing is incorrect.

> This code sets  module.exports to a variable called exports which then gets set to an object which gets exported.

What is actually happening is that the value `{ red, blue }` is being assigned to `module.exports`, and then that same value (`{ red, blue }`) is being assigned to `exports`.

In JavaScript and other languages with similar syntax (C, C++, C#, Java) `someAssignableThing = someValue` is treated as an *expression*, and you can use `a = b` as a sub-portion of other expressions and chain as many together as you want.

As an expression `someAssignableThing = someValue` equates to "assign `someValue` to `someAssignableThing` and evaluate to the value `someValue`".

So the statement:

```
a = b = c = d = e = 5;
```

would assign the value `5` to `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, and `e`.

It is a syntax error to have something on the left side of the `=` that cannot be assigned a value and that's why you get an error in the second case (you cannot assign a value to `5`).